# Hibernate do not save my records in the database but the primary key is incremented

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

Hibernate do not save my records in the database but the auto increment primary key is incremented.

> I have 5 users and each user has 10 records in mysql table X. Therefore
>   there should be 50 records altogether. But there are only 40 and there
>   is no error shown. Records of user 3 is not there in the database. But
>   the primary keys go from 1 to 50. Meaning it goes from 1-20 and then
>   start from 30 to 50.
>    21,22,23....etc are missing where the records of
>   user 3 should have been

My application log says that hibernate save method is called without an exception. Any ideas why this might have happened? I do not have mysql binary log enabled.

Comment: can you please post your save code? did you commit the transaction?

Comment: @joc code is too complicated and long to post here. I'm looping through users and adding their records into the database. So I'm using the same save method which is working for other users but not for user 3.

Comment: look like you delete some data. Check, where you can call for `delete from table `

Comment: if you cannot resume it to a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question does not fit SO rules....

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you are not handling transaction properly
If you are using Spring then add `@Transactional` annotation on your save method.

If it's plain java code then do manage transaction like this

```
try {  
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    tx = session.beginTransaction();  
    // save operation      
    tx.commit();  

} catch (Exception ex) {  
  ex.printStackTrace();  
  tx.rollback();  
} finally {
  session.close();
}
```